# How does c compiler parse composite type without identifier?

Tags: c, parsing

Considering the following `cdecl` examples:

```
cdecl> explain void(*signal(int, void (*)(int)))(int)
declare signal as function (int, pointer to function (int) returning void) returning pointer to function (int) returning void

cdecl> explain void (*)(int)
syntax error
```

I'm aware of the 'human' way to interpret `void (*)(int)` by trying to add imaginary identifier to the proper location, but wonder how compiler systematically determines it, obviously `cdecl` can't.

Comment: C11 [§6.7.4 Type names](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.7) defines how type names without an identifier are to be recognized by the compiler.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanLeffler! Could you add it as answer so I can accept.

Comment: I see I can't copy numbers accurately — 6.7.4 in my comment should be 6.7.7.  The link is correct.  ☹️

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C standard defines how to interpret type names without an identifier in [§6.7.7 Type names](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.7):

> ¶2 In several contexts, it is necessary to specify a type. This is accomplished using a type name, which is syntactically a declaration for a function or an object of that type that omits the identifier.

There's also a set of grammar productions that defines how this works.